# Inno Setup - Create directory in code section

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create directories in between the setup of the wizard. Is it possible to create those directories in the code section?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using `CreateDir` or `ForceDirectories`, both of which are documented in the Pascal Scripting Support Functions Reference section of the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of those trying to find the documentation mentioned in the comment.

[`CreateDir`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createdir.htm)
**Prototype:**
`function CreateDir(const Dir: string): Boolean;`

**Description:**
Creates a new directory. The return value is `True` if a new directory was successfully created, or `False` if an error occurred.

---

[`ForceDirectories`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_forcedirectories.htm)
**Prototype:**
`function ForceDirectories(Dir: string): Boolean;`

**Description:**
Creates all the directories along the specified directory path all at once. If the first directories in the path do exist, but the latter ones don't, `ForceDirectories` creates just the ones that don't exist. Returns `True` if successful, `False` otherwise.

---

Click [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) for the Inno Setup help documentation.